# Our EC2 server, unreachable for 30 minutes then came back. No error indicated. No action taken

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We have a `PHP` app running on a single instance `EC2`, `Ubuntu 16.04`, with `NGINX`, `PHP-FPM` upstream. We use an external service (pingdom) to monitor our web app. It's been a quiet month with 99.9% uptime.

Last night around 3am the web app was unreachable for 30 minutes, then it became reachable again. Nothing was done, and we noticed the outage only in the morning.

`NGINX` `access.log` shows a 30 min gap in the access requests matching the downtime. No requests were coming in during that time to `NGINX`, so I know it's not a failure upstream in the app or `PHP-FPM` (we had those before). `NGINX` error log is clean for that time. Needless to say the `PHP-FPM` and PHP logs are clean of errors for that time.

Any idea what this could have been? Where else should I look trying to understand why the server was unreachable (timeout) from the outside for 30 minutes and then just popped back to life without any correction done on my part? could this be something in AWS? Internet outage?

I would welcome any idea.

Comment: Are you in `us-east-2`? "Between 12:11 AM and 12:45 AM PDT we experienced impaired Internet connectivity in the US-EAST-2 Region. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally." http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: yes! I am in that region and the time matches. Write your response an an answer so I can credit you for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Between 12:11 AM and 12:45 AM PDT we experienced impaired Internet connectivity in the US-EAST-2 Region. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally.

https://status.aws.amazon.com/